# ANSI C: If a function pointer points to executable code does that mean less execution overhead than simply invoking the function?

Tags: c, optimization, function-pointers, c89

We know that using function pointers in C can be quite helpful when used in the proper scenarios (calling a function at runtime vs compile time, making the code more readable, etc.), but there isn't much literature around simple function invocation vs using a function pointer.

```
void foo(void) {
    printf("hello\n");
}

int testFcn(void) {

    // simple invokation
    foo();

    return 0;
}

// Or, declare function pointer and assign
void (*myFunc)(void) = foo;

int testFcn(myFunc) {

    // Function pointer invokation.
    myFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps the only real way to tell is to analyze the .lst files and .map files?

Comment: No, there is no less overhead.

Comment: Um... But your code sample makes an invocation *through function pointer* `myFunc`, yet calls it "simple invocation" in the comment. So, what exactly do you mean by "simple invocation" then?

Comment: "making the code more readable" umm... https://cdecl.org/  `char (*(*x())[5])()` sure... that's... rea... yeah...

Comment: Simply considering the dereferencing required to call the function from a function pointer means more overhead...

Comment: The C tag refer to standard C. ANSI-C is commonly uised for the ancient first version of the C standard from 28 years ago, resp. the one year older ANSI standard version (both are technically identical). None of them is standard C. While this should not be used for new code, if you ask about it, use the correct tag for questions. Otherwise you might get an answer based on modern C.

Comment: @Frankie_C Nah. On most CPUs, calling a function with a constant address or calling it through a register is more or less the same instruction timing.

Comment: A *function* also "points" to executable code.

Comment: A (dereferenced) function pointer cannot be *inlined*. And (IMHO) it cannot be predicted, so the instruction pipeline will stall.

Comment: @tofro If function pointer is in a register perhaps... and this is not as general as the  question is asking (ANSI-C). Getting in a deeper detail we have to consider that on some architectures a function pointer object is not even just an address, and in fact C99/C11 standards consider a function pointer object different from an object pointer, implying that in some cases the indirect call could be very expansive in terms of timing.

Comment: @AnT I apologize, the second "simple invokation" comment should have been removed. I will update the comment accordingly so as not to confuse.

Answer (score 7):

In general case, when function pointer is stored in data segment's memory, invoking a function through such a pointer will involve *more overhead*, not less overhead.

The real-life performance might vary greatly, depending on whether the pointer is in the CPU cache, already loaded into CPU register, properly predicted by branch prediction mechanism and other factors.

Comment: I'd mention that often the big performance loss from indirect call for smaller functions comes from missed opportunity for inlining.

Answer (score 3):

A call through a function pointer pretty much necessarily has *more*, not *less* overhead than a simple function call. Why? Simply because an indirect function  call using a function pointer makes it harder to do optimizations such as function inlining, because the *compiler* cannot deduce beforehand which function will be called.

Given your example code, a smart compiler can deduce that

```
void foo(void) {
    printf("hello\n");
}

int testFcn(void) {
    foo(); 
    return 0;
}
```

`foo` can be inlined into `testFcn` - as if it was written

```
int testFcn(void) {
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

yet the behaviour would be the same. However, such inlining cannot generally occur if a function pointer is used, because it can be changed before and between the invocations.

Answer (score 1):

What is the basis for this question?  What makes you think that using a function pointer could have *less* overhead than invoking the function directly?  Why would you expect that doing something *indirectly* would be faster than doing something *directly*?

Suppose that using a function pointer were somehow faster than invoking the function directly.  If so, then it would be a *trivial* optimization for compilers to automatically convert *all* functions to function pointers!  With such an optimization, you wouldn't be able to see any difference, so invoking via function pointers could never be observably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointer is NO less overhead than normal simply function call.

It allows you to use variable as function pointer, for example as parameter to function for callback, or any other usage.

```
void do_something(int (*get_value_callback)(void)) {
    int a;

    a = get_value_callback();
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

And then you can use it as this:

```
int func_ptr_1(void) { return 1; }
int func_ptr_2(void) { return 2; }

do_something(func_ptr_2); //Prints 1
do_something(func_ptr_2); //Prints 2
```

This is a example, how you can use function pointers acting like prototypes but there is no less overhead than in normal call. You can expect more overhead, not less. Real performance depends on many things and varies between CPUs.